# x greater than 0 implies x greater than or equal to 0

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, proof-explanation

Why is this statement true? All we know is that x is greater than 0, and it does seem like the converse muse be true.

Comment: The converse is *not* true. If it were, then from the true $5 \le 5$ would follow the false $5<5.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter what statements $p,q$ are, one can say if $p$ then ($p$ or $q$). Apply this to $x>0$ for $p$ and $x=0$ for $q.$

Comment: That will always be a true statement. But how does this make sense graphically?

Comment: This answers your question. It is unclear what else your are asking, although perhaps there is a number line answer: the set of numbers that satisfies the inequality $x > 0$ is a subset of the set of numbers that satisfy the inequality $x \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For the binary relation $''\geq''$  we have
$$
''\geq'' =  ''>''  \cup \, ''='' 
$$
Thus $''>''\, \subseteq \, ''\geq''$.